# How should the run block be dealt with in Angular unit tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

My understanding is that when you load your module in Angular unit tests, the `run` block gets called.

I'd think that if you're testing a component, you wouldn't want to simultaneously be testing the `run` block, because *unit* tests are supposed to just test one *unit*. Is that true?

If so, is there a way to prevent the `run` block from running? My research leads me to think that the answer is "no", and that the `run` block always runs when the module is loaded, but perhaps there's a way to override this. If not, how would I test the `run` block?

**Run block:**

```
function run(Auth, $cookies, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.user = {};
  Auth.getCurrentUser();
}
```

**Auth.getCurrentUser:**

```
getCurrentUser: function() {
  // user is logged in
  if (Object.keys($rootScope.user).length > 0) {
    return $q.when($rootScope.user);
  }
  // user is logged in, but page has been refreshed and $rootScope.user is lost
  if ($cookies.get('userId')) {
    return $http.get('/current-user')
      .then(function(response) {
        angular.copy(response.data, $rootScope.user);
        return $rootScope.user;
      })
    ;
  }
  // user isn't logged in
  else  {
    return $q.when({});
  }
}
```

**auth.factory.spec.js**

```
describe('Auth Factory', function() {
  var Auth, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $cookies, $q;
  var user = {
    username: 'a',
    password: 'password',
  };
  var response = {
    _id: 1,
    local: {
      username: 'a',
      role: 'user'
    }
  };

  function isPromise(el) {
    return !!el.$$state;
  }

  beforeEach(module('mean-starter', 'ngCookies', 'templates'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_Auth_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$cookies_, _$q_) {
    Auth = _Auth_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $cookies = _$cookies_;
    $q = _$q_;
  }));
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('#signup', function() {
    $rootScope.user = {};
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/users', user).respond(response);
    spyOn(angular, 'copy').and.callThrough();
    spyOn($cookies, 'put').and.callThrough();
    var retVal = Auth.signup(user);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(angular.copy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(response, $rootScope.user);
    expect($cookies.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith('userId', 1);
    expect(isPromise(retVal)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('#login', function() {
    $rootScope.user = {};
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login', user).respond(response);
    spyOn(angular, 'copy').and.callThrough();
    spyOn($cookies, 'put').and.callThrough();
    var retVal = Auth.login(user);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(angular.copy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(response, $rootScope.user);
    expect($cookies.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith('userId', 1);
    expect(isPromise(retVal)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('#logout', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/logout').respond();
    spyOn(angular, 'copy').and.callThrough();
    spyOn($cookies, 'remove');
    Auth.logout();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(angular.copy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, $rootScope.user);
    expect($cookies.remove).toHaveBeenCalledWith('userId');
  });

  describe('#getCurrentUser', function() {
    it('User is logged in', function() {
      $rootScope.user = response;
      spyOn($q, 'when').and.callThrough();
      var retVal = Auth.getCurrentUser();
      expect($q.when).toHaveBeenCalledWith($rootScope.user);
      expect(isPromise(retVal)).toBe(true);
    });
    it('User is logged in but page has been refreshed', function() {
      $cookies.put('userId', 1);
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/current-user').respond(response);
      spyOn(angular, 'copy').and.callThrough();
      var retVal = Auth.getCurrentUser();
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(angular.copy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(response, $rootScope.user);
      expect(isPromise(retVal)).toBe(true);
    });
    it("User isn't logged in", function() {
      $rootScope.user = {};
      $cookies.remove('userId');
      spyOn($q, 'when').and.callThrough();
      var retVal = Auth.getCurrentUser();
      expect($q.when).toHaveBeenCalledWith({});
      expect(isPromise(retVal)).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

---

**Attempt 1:**

```
beforeEach(module('mean-starter', 'ngCookies', 'templates'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_Auth_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$cookies_, _$q_) {
  Auth = _Auth_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $cookies = _$cookies_;
  $q = _$q_;
}));
beforeEach(function() {
  spyOn(Auth, 'getCurrentUser');
});
afterEach(function() {
  expect(Auth.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

This doesn't work. The `run` block is run when the module is loaded, so `Auth.getCurrentUser()` is called before the spy is set up.

```
Expected spy getCurrentUser to have been called.
```

---

**Attempt 2:**

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_Auth_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$cookies_, _$q_) {
  Auth = _Auth_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $cookies = _$cookies_;
  $q = _$q_;
}));
beforeEach(function() {
  spyOn(Auth, 'getCurrentUser');
});
beforeEach(module('mean-starter', 'ngCookies', 'templates'));
afterEach(function() {
  expect(Auth.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

This doesn't work because `Auth` isn't available to be injected before my app module is loaded.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth
```

---

**Attempt 3:**

As you can see, there's a chicken-egg problem here. I need to inject Auth and set up the spy before the module is loaded, but I can't because Auth isn't available to be injected before the module is loaded.

[This](https://medium.com/@a_eife/testing-config-and-run-blocks-in-angularjs-1809bd52977e) blog posts mentions the chicken-egg problem and provides an interesting potential solution. The author proposes that I should create my `Auth` service manually using `$provide` *before* I load my module. Since I'm creating the service, not injecting it, I could do it before the module is loaded, and I could set up the spy. Then when the module is loaded, it'd use this created mock service.

Here is his example code:

```
describe('example', function () {
    var loggingService;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('example', function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('loggingService', {
                start: jasmine.createSpy()
            });
        });
        inject(function (_loggingService_) {
            loggingService = _loggingService_;
        });
    });
    it('should start logging service', function() {
        expect(loggingService.start).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The problem with this, is that I need my `Auth` service! I only would want to use the mock one for the `run` block; I need my real `Auth` service elsewhere so I could test it.

I guess that I could create the actual `Auth` service using `$provide`, but that feels wrong.

---

Final question - for whatever code I end up using to deal with this `run` block problem, is there a way for me to extract it out so I don't have to re-write it for each of my spec files? The only way I could think to do it would be to use some sort of global function.

---

**auth.factory.js**

```
angular
  .module('mean-starter')
  .factory('Auth', Auth)
;

function Auth($http, $state, $window, $cookies, $q, $rootScope) {
  return {
    signup: function(user) {
      return $http
        .post('/users', user)
        .then(function(response) {
          angular.copy(response.data, $rootScope.user);
          $cookies.put('userId', response.data._id);
          $state.go('home');
        })
      ;
    },
    login: function(user) {
      return $http
        .post('/login', user)
        .then(function(response) {
          angular.copy(response.data, $rootScope.user);
          $cookies.put('userId', response.data._id);
          $state.go('home');
        })
      ;
    },
    logout: function() {
      $http
        .get('/logout')
        .then(function() {
          angular.copy({}, $rootScope.user);
          $cookies.remove('userId');
          $state.go('home');
        })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('Problem logging out.');
        })
      ;
    },
    getCurrentUser: function() {
      // user is logged in
      if (Object.keys($rootScope.user).length > 0) {
        return $q.when($rootScope.user);
      }
      // user is logged in, but page has been refreshed and $rootScope.user is lost
      if ($cookies.get('userId')) {
        return $http.get('/current-user')
          .then(function(response) {
            angular.copy(response.data, $rootScope.user);
            return $rootScope.user;
          })
        ;
      }
      // user isn't logged in
      else  {
        return $q.when({});
      }
    }
  };
}
```

---

Edit - failed attempt + successful attempt:

```
beforeEach(module('auth'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_Auth_) {
  Auth = _Auth_;
  spyOn(Auth, 'requestCurrentUser');
}));
beforeEach(module('mean-starter', 'ngCookies', 'templates'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_Auth_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$cookies_, _$q_) {
  // Auth = _Auth_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $cookies = _$cookies_;
  $q = _$q_;
}));
// beforeEach(function() {
//   spyOn(Auth, 'getCurrentUser');
// });
afterEach(function() {
  expect(Auth.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work (independent of the problem with using `inject` twice).

I was trying to get around having to use `$provide` as that initially felt hacky/weird to me. After thinking about it some more though, I now feel that `$provide` is fine, and that following your suggestion to use `mock-auth` is fantastic!!! Both worked for me.

In `auth.factory.spec.js` I just loaded the `auth` module (I'm calling it `auth`, not `mean-auth`) without loading `mean-starter`. This doesn't have the `run` block problem because that module doesn't have the `run` block code, but it allows me to test my `Auth` factory. Elsewhere, this works:

```
beforeEach(module('mean-starter', 'templates', function($provide) {
  $provide.value('Auth', {
    requestCurrentUser: jasmine.createSpy()
  });
}));
```

As does the fantastic `mock-auth` solution:

**auth.factory.mock.js**

```
angular
  .module('mock-auth', [])
  .factory('Auth', Auth)
;

function Auth() {
  return {
    requestCurrentUser: jasmine.createSpy()
  };
}
```

**user.service.spec.js**

```
beforeEach(module('mean-starter', 'mock-auth', 'templates'));
```

Comment: off-topic to your question, but you should know that `.run` doesn't wait for `$http` to complete. If anything in the app relies on the result being there, you have a race condition. Typically, you'd use `resolve` if you were using `ngRoute` or `ui.router`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My understanding is that when you load your module in Angular unit
>   tests, the run block gets called.

Correct.

> I'd think that if you're testing a component, you wouldn't want to
>   simultaneously be testing the run block, because unit tests are
>   supposed to just test one unit. Is that true?

Also correct, in that right now you are effectively testing the integration of `Auth` and your run block, and there is no isolation of one from the other.

> If so, is there a way to prevent the run block from running? My
>   research leads me to think that the answer is "no", and that the run
>   block always runs when the module is loaded, but perhaps there's a way
>   to override this. If not, how would I test the run block?

As implemented, no you cannot prevent the run block from running. However, it remains possible with some minor refactoring as your question is ultimately one of modularisation. Without being able to see your module declaration, I would imagine it looks something like this:

```
angular.module('mean-starter', ['ngCookies'])

  .factory('Auth', function($cookies) {
    ...
  });

  .run(function(Auth, $rootScope) {
    ...
  });
```

This pattern can be broken into modules to support testability (and module reusability):

```
angular.module('mean-auth', ['ngCookies'])

  .factory('Auth', function() {
    ...
  });

angular.module('mean-starter', ['mean-auth'])

  .run(function(Auth, $rootScope) {
    ...
  });
```

This now allows you to test your `Auth` factory in isolation by loading the `mean-auth` module only into its test.

While this solves the problem of your run block interfering with your unit tests for `Auth`, you still face the problem of mocking `Auth.getCurrentUser` so as to test your run block in isolation. The blog post you referenced is correct in that you should be looking to leverage the configuration stage of the module to stub/spy on dependencies used during the run stage. Therefore, in your test:

```
module('mean-starter', function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('Auth', {
    getCurrentUser: jasmine.createSpy()
  });
});
```

As to your final question, you can create reusable mocks by declaring them as modules. For example, if you wanted to create a reusable mock factory for `Auth` you define it in a separate file loaded prior to your unit tests:

```
angular.module('mock-auth', [])

 .factory('Auth', function() {
   return {
     getCurrentUser: jasmine.createSpy()
   };
 });
```

and then load it in your tests subsequent to any module in which you require it, as angular will overwrite any service with the same name:

```
module('mean-starter', 'mock-auth');
```

Comment: Thank you! A few questions (I'll investigate them myself too, but also figured I'd ask you): 1) Re: mocking `Auth.getCurrentUser`, is it necessary to use `$provide`? Couldn't I just use `spyOn(Auth, 'getCurrentUser')` after loading `mean-auth` and injecting `Auth`? 2) Currently, my `Auth` factory is using `$rootScope` to keep track of the currently logged in user. By using a `mock-auth` module, its `$rootScope` wouldn't be the same as `mean-starter`'s `$rootScope` right? I figured this was a good use case for `$rootScope`, but I'm thinking about how I could refactor it now.

Comment: I edited my question to include my current `auth.factory.js`. After thinking about it some more, I'm not sure how the separate `mean-auth` module would work. For the first 3 methods, I could just return the promise after `.post`/`.get` and do the rest of the logic in the controller. But for `getCurrentUser`, I'd like to conditionally make the HTTP request depending on whether or not the current user is already available. But how would `mean-auth` know about the current user? I guess I could make this check elsewhere?

Comment: 1. You don't need `$provide` for testing `mean-auth` as its state is no longer influenced by your run block. You do need to use it for testing the `mean-starter` however, as the run block fires immediately.
2. The `$rootScope` will be the same. Angular's mock `module` collects the defined modules prior to creating the injector, whereupon the $rootScope exists as the parent (i.e. top-level) scope for the "application".

Comment: `mean-auth` will know about the current user because, in being loaded by `mean-starter`, its `$rootScope` is the same (in layman's terms, the root scope is "attached" to wherever `ng-app` is declared, and so all modules therein will inherit it).

Comment: Thanks, I understand (2) and what you said about `$rootScope` being attached to `ng-app`. I'm still unclear on (1) though. Why doesn't the code in my edit work? a) My thinking is that I'd be spying on `Auth.requestCurrentUser` (had to change the method name), and so when the `run` block of `mean-starter` runs, it would be a stub, not the real function. b) I'm getting an error saying `Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!`. Is that because I'm using `inject()` twice? If so, how would I get around this?